# Equilibrium Question?

Tags: torque, equilibrium

For the figure shown a 5.0m long board is hinged 1.75m from its right end and allowed to rotate freely. You push with an upward force of 250N on the end of the board away from the pivot. A bucket of mass 75kg is placed on the board. The board has a mass of 65kg and is of  uniform shape and mass distribution. Where must the 75kg bucket be placed so that the board is in equilibrium?

[image]

So far I set up the problem like this:

(T)Torque=0

T=FD-MGR

(+250N because clockwise)

+250(3.25m)-(9.81)(75kg-65kg)R = 0

Solving for R

Is this the correct setup for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must consider all the torques in your problem. They are four in this case :

- $T_f$, torque created by the force of 250 N ;
- $T_{P_1}$, torque created by the mass of the board on the left of pivot ;
- $T_{P_2}$, torque created by the mass of the board on the right of pivot ;
- $T_{B}$, torque created by the mass of the bucket.

For compute $T_{P_1}$ and $T_{P_2}$ you must consider that the weight applies to center of gravity of each part of the board on either side of the pivot.

Last, you have to solve  $T_f + T_{P_1} + T_{P_2} + T_{B} = 0 $

Comment: i.e., the OP's approach is more or less correct, BUT you need to take care about where the weight of the plank acts.

Comment: what did you call OP?